# Forking actions/checkout@v2 at organization level to be used repo's github actions

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

### Problem:

Inherently, github actions has no information about the code within the repo it's being run in. To rid that problem, there is the `actions/checkout` workflow that is the defacto start of most workflows.

Our enterprise account got locked down to only local actions only:
[image]

Because of this, we are not able to use the `actions/checkout@v2` at the start of our workflow, thus rendering our Github Actions useless.

### Proposed Solution

Fork the `actions/checkout` repo as a submodule of a repo and use that reference in my code like so:

```yaml
steps:
  - uses: <enterprise_name>/<repo_name>/checkout@main
```

When running this action as a test, I get this error message:

```
Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under
'/home/runner/work/_actions/<enterprise_name>/<repo_name>/main/checkout'. 
Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?
```

---

### So my question:

Is there a way to run a forked or local version of `actions/checkout`? The above example is telling me, I can't run a local version of `actions/checkout` because I have clone the repo which is ironic error.

Answer (score 4):

You need to push the `actions/checkout` repo into an internal or public repo on your enterprise. Then update your workflow to reference `organization/repo@2` instead.

After forking the `actions/checkout` repo to my `jessehouwing-actions` this would result in the following update of the YAML:

```
steps:
  # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

Would become:

```
steps:
  # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
  - uses: jessehouwing-actions/checkout@v3
```

Don't use submodules.

Comment: Cloning repos and pushing them into a org repo worked. I was able to refer to the code using: `organization/repo@my_branch`

Comment: could you share the yaml file?